# Rails Routes get :this[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I'm having problems with getting the correct route set up in my routes file.
I have a controller for Events.
Within the Events Controller I have an action called "people" which looks a little like this:

```
def people
    @people = Event.find_by_sql(["sql that joins three tables to get the data I need;", params[:id]])
end
```

In my routes I have:

```
resources :events do
    collection do
      get :somethingelse
      get :people
    end
end
```

If I hardcode my params[:id] before my "find_by_sql" it works just fine when I visit ".../events/people" However, if I try to do something like ".../events/5/people" I get the "No route matches [GET] "/events/5/people" error.

I am sure I am missing something simple in my routes file.
Can anyone provide me with the part that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's not on collection, it's on member

```
collection do
  get :somethingelse
end
member do
  get :people
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach:

```
id = 1
User.find_by_sql(['select * from users where id = ?', id])`
```